# Measure the duration of visit on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

there is a requirement to measure how long for and how often Visualforce page has been opened.

I can imagine recording opens via custom controller & SOQL is easy, but how about stay duration?

Any ideas?

dzh

Comment: I think only way is JS....
And of course some label/custom setting to store information

Comment: Yes JS, but have you got more details?

Answer (score 2):

Use those JS functions

```
window.onload=openingCode(){SomeJavaScriptCode};


window.onbeforeunload = closingCode{SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

I did not set any operations inside, just because I think it would be best if you decide how handle calculation and saving data :)

Comment: Thanks, that is actually what I was looking for. I was always wondering - how reliability onbeforeunload works? Does Google Analytics use the same function?